# Android - Intent to play a video externally at a given time position

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I am playing a video externally with a code similar to :

```
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

I need to had 2 more features :

1) I want to specify the time position where to start the video.

2) Maybe more difficult, but I want to retrieve the position of the video when you user stop watching it and returns to my app.

Could you help me to setup the intent for question 1)

And do you have any clue for question 2) knowing that a video external player like VLC won't code for me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to specify the time position where to start the video

`ACTION_VIEW` does not offer any extras related to this. Few video player apps will support this, as a result.

> 2) Maybe more difficult, but I want to retrieve the position of the video when you user stop watching it and returns to my app.

`ACTION_VIEW` does not offer anything related to this either.

You need to implement video playback within your app itself, using:

- `VideoView`
- `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`
- ExoPlayer
- LibVLC
- etc.

Alternatively, you could force the user to install a particular video player that does offer your desired feature set, such as [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have no other choice but to implement my own video playback I think.